# datagridview not updating automatically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

The datagirdview is  not updating after immediate in inserting records.

`Private Sub updatedgv()
        Using congv As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=..\library.mdb")
            Dim strgv As String = "select * from NormalTransaction where RegNo='" & txt_RegisterNo.Text & "'"
            Dim cmdgv As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strgv, congv)
            Dim sdagv As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdgv)
            Dim dsgv As DataSet = New DataSet("gvSet")
            sdagv.Fill(dsgv)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dsgv
            DataGridView1.DataMember = dsgv.Tables(0).TableName
        End Using
    End Sub`

please help me to solve this.

Comment: are you sure that you call `updatedgv` after inserting into your `table` ??

Comment: Yes.. I m calling updategv

Comment: If you put a break point where you set the datagridview datasource to the reloaded data put a break point.  I would look at the data table and make sure new data is there.  Maybe the issue is with the data being saved.

Comment: Its my silly mistake i was calling updategv() before closing connection thats y its not updating. Thanks hector and @ken tucker.